# WordPress doesn't send a notification email when submitting a comment using REST API

Tags: rest-api

When I submit a comment on the WordPress website, it sends me a notification email.
but when I submit a comment through REST API, WordPress doesn't send me a notification email.
What should I do to make WordPress send a notification email when I submit a comment with REST API?

Comment: Never really used the wordpress api but here's what I would do. If the response was successful (don't know how wordpress returns it) use wp_mail to send yourself or the admin (if it's not you) an email

Answer (score 3):

Here's an untested suggestion for the REST API case:

```
add_action( 'rest_after_insert_comment', 'wp_new_comment_notify_moderator' );
```

emulating the existing:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'wp_new_comment_notify_moderator' );
```

Note the different callback inputs between actions and that we use that `get_comment()` should handle both comment ID or comment object as an input.

Comment: When I use "rest_after_insert_comment" this error appears: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?post=6194. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
"

Comment: That sounds normal for cross-origin requests, not sure how that could be related to the hooking.